# Libgdx Game - Texture Scaling

Tags: android, libgdx, game-engine

I am using LibGdx to develop a simple game for Android devices. I wish to show a progress bar using the Texture  by scaling it up / down. When we do scaling the image is changing in its shape. Could you please let me know a best approach to achieve the below mentioned scenario.

[image]
Scale up is fine..
[image]
Scale down is really a problem.
[image]

Comment: Use a NinePatch and set the left and right width to a fixed value.

Comment: is that possible inLibGdx

Comment: Yes, otherwise I would not tell you to do that.

Comment: When using 9 patch do I need to take care anything in coding ?.. simple scaling will scale the middle part ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it purely by scaling, you can do one of the following

- Use a mask on the green bit (use for example the blue part as a mask)
- Chop the green part up in three parts: two for the round end caps and a rectangular middle piece you can scale. The problem with this is that the smalles progress you can display will be one endcap.

Comment: Not if you want to keep the round green caps (which, in my opinion, are not great from a usability perspective - maybe draw the percentage number on top of it).