# How to edit png files in 9patch to fit into progress Bar

Tags: animation, libgdx, progress-bar, nine-patch

I want to fit my `insideProgressBarTexture` into my identicall but diffrent color 
 `ousideProgressBarTexture`. Im use 9patch images but whenever its get small it does not look very good (the `insideProgressBarTexture` is not fit into `ousideProgressBarTexture`)[image: example1][image]

EDIT: The purple image is a 9patch image but I dont know that I creating it right. Maybe the stretch region is wrong.
[image]

Ive found [similiar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28825128/libgdx-game-texture-scaling) but I dont quite understand how to set the left and right width to a fixed value

EDIT 2: Ive use all of the options (Stretch region Content padding Optical bounds) but rounded end sides still stretching whenever I try to change the width of element

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The image shown looks like it isn't a 9 patch image. Check the image is a 9 patch image by looking at the 1 pixel border around the main image.

Is there a fully opaque line? 
If so, how long and which border is it facing(top, left, right, bottom)?

If there is an opaque line, check it only covers the center portion(the part you want to expand when stretched). From the image shown, your opaque line should start after the curve of the end caps finishes.

edit:

You should layout your patches like the image below so the corners don't get deformed during stretching.

[image: Example 9 Patch layout]

Comment: The image is shown from within the game itself, so no opaque lines would be visible.

Comment: The opaque lines are only used to define the 9 patch sizes and must exists for the image to work as a 9 patch image. In your assets folder open the image with an image editing tool and check the lines exist.

Comment: Yes they should exist in the original image, but not when being rendered.

Comment: Do they exist in the original image is what I'm asking, not if they are being rendered.